# Prevent APEX from Sending email copies to code developer

Tags: apex

Hi Im sending emails using the following code:

```
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {inquery.email__c};
       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
       mail.setTargetObjectId(inquery.OwnerID);
       mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
       mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
       mail.setUseSignature(false);
       mail.setBccSender(false);
       mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName=:'Invitation_to_register’];
          mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r =
           Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
```

As the developer, I keep on receiving a copy of all the emails that are sent out,

I have been told this is because I have set the setTargetObjectId:

```
mail.setTargetObjectId(inquery.OwnerID);
```

But I need that line because of the Email Template,
If I remove it I will get the following error:

REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing targetObjectId with template:

What can I use instead of OwnerID?

Comment: Are you trying to log these against the inquery record?

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not sure what you are asking! Could you please restate the question?

Comment: I was curious if you were trying to log these anywhere. The idea that you have an enquiry object makes me wonder if they should actually be Leads.

Comment: Well the inquery object represents an inquiry database that shows our new leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider linking your "Inquery" to a contact, instead. This way, instead of specifying to addresses, you can just specify the contact to send to-- set the target object Id to the Contact related to the "inquery".

Comment: The inquiry is not a contact, its just a lead.

Comment: The same principle applies, then. Using a lead will allow you to correctly email the individual while specifying a template without spamming the system administrator.

Comment: Sorry, i mean that the Inquiry does not exist in any other database, only in the "Inquery" database.

Comment: While I'm not certain of the purpose of the Inquery object, I can almost certainly say that you want to have a record created for the lead/contact/whomever. If this means you have to create it behind-the-scenes with a trigger, you're better off doing so instead of trying to jerry-rig the system to do something it's not designed to do.

Comment: Completely agree

Comment: So your saying i can create a Lead or Contact for the person? because the Lead might work for me,

Comment: Definitely. People are meant to be interacted with, while custom objects are just things (and not people). Tracking them as leads would be advisable given all the features that leads offer over a custom object, include web capture, assignment rules, mass emails, campaign management, and so on.

Comment: Right, why try to reinvent the wheel.  Leverage the tools that the platform has created for you

Answer (score 0):

how about a chatter free user ;-) I think this should work but the email address will be spammed... 
The question is what happens with limits, I am not sure if it then counts against the 1000 email per day

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about replacing the Email Template with some HTML markup with setHtmlBody? It is less ideal to not have the email template, but you can only work within the limits of the platform.

The best case scenario is probably using something like a custom setting and a Long or Rich Text Area to define the "template", include some tokens for replacing fields, and in your code pull back the markup and replace any tokens. That way you can make edits later without having to deal with modifying APEX.

Comment: Well that's not an option, because the person who updates the templates is not a programmer, and they just want an easy template to change and add attachments to as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a template, then there is no way to leave out the SetTargetObjectId().  If you want to be able to not have the email go to you the developer you can

1. Change the owner of the Inquery to who you would like it to go to
2. Add a Contact Lookup field to the Inquery object that specifies a
   contact
3. Do not use an email template, and create the html for the email
   within your Apex

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setTargetObjectId.htm

Comment: I mentioned option 2 myself. It's the most sensible way to accomplish this.

Comment: The inquiry is not a contact, its just a lead.

Comment: ok, then you just need to create a lookup to a lead rather than a contact.  SFDCFox is correct, same principal applies.  The SetTargetObjectId() method specifies either a Contact, Lead or User.  So it will work with a lead as well

Comment: I totally agree with sfdcfox, that option 2 is by far the most sensible, just offering a few other options

Comment: Sorry, i mean that the Inquiry does not exist in any other database, only in the "Inquery" database.

Comment: See sfdcfox comment in his answer.  He puts it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The `mail.setTargetObjectId()` method chooses the record you want to pull fields from for your template.

I suggest using `mail.setTargetObjectId(inquery.id)`, then in your template, you can access the Owner's User Fields like `{!InqueryCustomObj__c.Owner.Name}`, etc.

Comment: Do you mind if i ask why i need to add {!InqueryCustomObj__c.Owner.Name} afterwards, especially that when i just use ID it works?

Comment: I might have given a nonsense answer.  What is the Object associated with the Email Template you are using?  If that Object is the User Standard Object, then yes, you need to set the TargetObjectId to a UserId.  But which one?  You are currently setting it to the OwnerId of the inquery Instance.  Is this what you want?   Or do you want whoever the current user is to get the email?  Then you should set the TargetObjectId to UserInfo.getUserId()

Comment: I thought Email templates are Standard Objects? i am setting the TargetObjectId to the inquirer ID, is that correct?

Comment: Who's the Inquirer (who do you want the email sent to)?  The current User executing the code?  If so, then have `mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId)`

Comment: If the `inquirer` is referenced on your sObject record somewhere (could the the OwnerId, CreatedById, etc.), use that